# Async in a Async task

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I put the following code in the `doInBackground()` in another `AsyncTask` which this `HttpPostHandler` contain another `AsyncTask`. Then the `handler.get()` just keep loading.
Anyone got any idea about this? 
Is this the problem about the threads???

**Code:**

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
                champ = Utility.getCounter("test");

                this.wait(3);
                }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In Utility:

```
public static int getCounter(String code) {
    HttpPostHandler handler = new HttpPostHandler();
    try {
        handler.execute(counter_URL + code);
        handler.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String html = handler.getResultJSONString();
    TagNode tagNode;

    ...
}
```

The following is the HttpPostHandler AsyncTask

```
    public class HttpPostHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private String url;
        private String resultJSONString=null;
        private JSONObject resultJSON;

        public String getResultJSONString() {
            return resultJSONString;
        }

        public void setResultJSONString(String resultJSONString) {
            this.resultJSONString = resultJSONString;
        }

        private static String toUTF8(InputStream is){
            //InputStream is = resEntity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader isr = null;
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8");
                Reader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
                int ch;
                while((ch = in.read()) != -1){
                    buffer.append((char)ch);
                }
                isr.close();
                is.close();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String result = "";
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try {
                    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(params[0]);
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get); 
                    Log.d("danny", "response = "+response);
                    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                    if (resEntity != null) {
                        result = toUTF8(resEntity.getContent());
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
                }
                setResultJSONString(result);
                return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            resultJSONString = result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running in API 11 (3.0) or later, you can change your `handler.execute(counter_URL + code);` to `handler.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, counter_URL + code);`

This allows for multiple AsyncTasks to be run simultaneously.

Comment: This works for me! Can u explain me more how this solved this? Is this mean my main thread stuck by the handler.get() ?? thx~

Comment: Android by default only allows for 1 AsyncTask to run at once (maybe to avoid multi-threading issues? Not too sure). In API 11 they introduced the executeOnExecutor method which essentially lets more than one instance of AsyncTask to be executed at the same time.

Comment: But my original handler.get() just non stop loading instead of loading slow. So i have no idea why multi thread helps? thx~

Comment: When your 'handler.execute()' reached 'HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);' in doInBackground, it couldn't execute because it was waiting for the 'onPostExecute()' callback from the initial AsyncTask which it could never reach because at that point you were waiting for the HttpResponse from the 2nd AsyncTask before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

Use publish progress method of asynctask class in doinbackground() instead of direct call "handler.execute".

Call "handler.execute" in onprogressupdate() and call publish progress in doInBackground.

Comment: Could u explain more about "Use publish progress method" thx~

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of publish progress:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
```

}

please voteup or mark true if it is helpful for you.